# SQL : Sorting data by fields which are not in select and group by clause

Tags: sql, sorting

I have a SQL query.
Join of two columns. 
I want to sort my search results by a column of the child table which is neither in select clause not in group by ( as I cannot group by it and cannot include it in the select ).
Is there some way I can achieve it?

Comment: hmmm why can't you group by it or include it in the select? if this is the case then you can't order by it as you probably have to aggregate it out some way, i.e. MAX(Field). Please explain further.

Comment: Adding to select will bring duplicate in the records as it will effect the distinct clause. Same is the case with grouping.

Comment: If it's not in `SELECT` nor `GROUP BY`, then there won't be any difference even if you could "sort" by it. The same result would appear, so there'd be no point in "sorting" the result by it. (It's not in the result.)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In **SQL Server**, it results in **error**

```
Column "test2.DATE" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.:
```

Fiddle here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d3d28/1

In **Oracle**, it results in **error**

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

    With test2 as
    (
        SELECT 1 ID,    'Hari'  fName,30 KEYID ,sysdate DATEE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 1,   'Hari'  ,20 , sysdate FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 2,   'John'  ,55, sysdate FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 2,   'John'  ,89, sysdate FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 2,   'John'  ,38, sysdate FROM DUAL
    )
    select id, fname, sum(keyid) from test2
    group by id, fname
    order by dateE desc;
```

---

---

So, in oracle, it is advisable to include the child-table column in your select clause. In your display UI Logic/resultset processing logic, you can consider ignoring the column.

Comment: Can you suggest some solution or alternate to this query.

Comment: @user3867673: Refer the last line in my answer. Include the column also and ignore it in your processing logic

Comment: Adding to select will bring duplicate in the records as it will effect the distinct clause.

Comment: Post the table structure of your query in fiddle and let me know the desired output. Will help in getting output.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make sense to order by a field that you are removing duplicates from, since some of the values that are removed could affect the sort order. Just using the example of Hari and John above, imagine this data:

```
1, 'Hari', 4
1, 'Hari', 6
2, 'John', 5
2, 'John', 7
2, 'John', 8
```

If you want these to be ordered Hari then John, because Hari has the lowest sort field and John has the next lowest (i.e. for the purposes of ordering, you ignore the sort field values 6, 7 and 8) then order by Min(SortField)

Again, using Nishanthi's example, the query would become something like this:

```
select id, fname, sum(keyid) from test2
    group by id, fname
    order by Min(dateE) desc;
```